# org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After I updates Android Studio to 3.4 it's not able to find `org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable` anymore.

When searching for updates I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable
```

And when trying to update Gradle I get this:

```
Unable to load class 'org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I already tried the solutions from the error, but none worked.

I'm using Android Studio 3.4 for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android studio 3.4 lack "rhino" library. This is used to process java script in proxy url.
Copy rhino-1.7.10.jar from 3.3.1 works for me.
Also you could change proxy settings do not use 'proxy url'.

Ref.: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131666743

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too, I was using the university's wi-fi (which places me behind a firewall). I had to change the proxy and it all went well. To do so go to:

1. Settings in android studio (ctrl + alt + s)
2. Appearance & Behavior
3. System Settings
4. HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download gradle from here:[Gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) then turn to `File -> Settings -> Build`, `Execution`, `Deployment ->Build Tools -> Gradle ->Use local gradle` distribution then input your gradle install path. (For example, ~/android-studio/gradle/gradle-5.1.1 )

It works for me. (English is not my native language, grammar mistakes are inevitable, I am very sorry!)