Unable to add org.mozilla.javascript.Context; & import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
Unable to import org.mozilla.javascript.Context; & import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
Added

Added libs.rhino.android dependencies already in build.gradle.kts (app)


Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

OK Sure, will remeber it Thanks @aled

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55862349/6059583 check this bro

Finally added rhino jar into lib folder and project working fine.
